# Is OpenCV limited to only Haar cascades? How can I implement my own model into OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, neural-network, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I want to use a webcam to identify faces in OpenCV. I am very new to this library and Python itself. I want to use a Siamese network trained on a single face, but from past experience with examples online, I noticed that only Haar Cascades are used; I am aware this is simply to find faces.

I wish to know if I can use a pre-trained model to then identify faces after finding them with the Haar Cascade.

If I asked in the wrong forum, please kindly transfer me to the appropriate one. I just really need answers as this is for my project.

Thanks

Comment: opencv has several detector/classifier function. CascadeClassifier can be used (haae and lbp), SVM e.g. with HogDescriptor, DNN in general (e.g. you siamese network).

Comment: and for recognition there is another module, FaceRecognizer or similaer, providing different algorithms like LBPH or EigenFaces

Comment: I was certainly very confused, but these have been clarified. After recognizing I intend to identify the face. I can **definitely** create a function running some OpenCV modules, "extract" the face so that it is my only "focus," then in a later function, use, say VGGFace or my Siamese network, to identify the face recognized by the CascadeClassifier?

Comment: yes sure. The first task, the "extraction" is called object detection. So in your case you want to detect faces. You can use opencv's pretrained cascade classifiers, which were state of the art somewhere around 2007? Afaik, dlib has some better face detectors. Nowadays, you probably find some nice deep learning based face detectors, too. OpenCV's DNN module provides different methods to read networks from tensorflow, darknet, etc. and if all your layer types are supported, you can use the network. But maybe you have to interpret the output of the network yourself, since it's general purpose.